# Scale my Text Object

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

How do you shrink or resize a text object?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like any other object, just press "**s**" and scale it. Then you can press "**ctrl+a**" to apply scale

Answer (score 0):

You must *Scale* it. The syntax is below.

`s [{[Shift + ]x, y, z} <factor of scale>]`

- `s` initiates the transform. If one moves the cursor to or from the object, it will scale it to the degree that the cursor has moved.
- `s [{x, y, z}]` scales the object along an axis to the degree that the cursor has moved.
- `s [<factor of scale>]` scales the object to the factor specified.
- `s [{x, y, z} <factor of scale>]` scales the object along an axis to the factor specified.

`Shift + an axis` means you scale on the two axes not specified.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer, can they tell me why so I can improve it?

Comment: I think it is written in an unnecessarily complex and unclear way for something that is so simple.

Comment: @RayMairlot Ok, but when [formatting code](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-read-command-syntax-2618082), it's correct.

Comment: But it's not code...

Comment: @RayMairlot But it is syntax, which is similar to code.